# expo calendar app crash because of permissions

Tags: react-native, expo

this is my config in app.json

```
 "plugins": [
      [
        "expo-calendar",
        {
          "calendarPermission": "Allow $(PRODUCT_NAME) to access your calendar"
        }
      ]
    ]
```

this code is in the index of my app but the app crashing when it finish bundle

```
 useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      await Calendar.requestCalendarPermissionsAsync();
    })();
  }, []);
```

This is the error am getting

*This app has crashed because it attempted to access privacy-sensitive data without a usage
description.  The app's Info.plist must contain an NSCalendarsUsageDescription key with a string*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix this error, you need to add the NSCalendarsUsageDescription key to your Info.plist file, which is located in the ios folder of your project. This key should have a string value that explains why your app needs to access the user's calendar like this:

```
<key>NSCalendarsUsageDescription</key>
<string>Allow $(PRODUCT_NAME) to access your calendar</string>
```

Comment: thank you but am curious as to why expo did have it in their docs